# How to get bounds of visible map with flutter google_maps plugin?

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I'm trying to find out what is the bounding box of the visible part of google map in flutter's google maps plugin.

Is it possible to get it?

If not is it possible to calculate the bounding box based on zoom level and latitude, longitude of the map center?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That would be [`GoogleMapController.getVisibleRegion()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMapController/getVisibleRegion.html)

Comment: Great to see this feature finally added.

Comment: is this still accurate?

Answer (score 3):

Be careful, `GoogleMapController.getVisibleRegion()` returns a `LatLngBounds` (a rectangle) and if your map has a tilt then it should not be a rectangle but a trapezoid!

The issue is in the plugin implementation where the returned result is computed only from `latLngBounds` field whereas it should be computed from `farLeft`, `farRight`, `nearLeft`, `nearRight` fields.
Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/model/VisibleRegion

So `GoogleMapController.getVisibleRegion()` is not accurate and can't be used if there's a tilt.

For reference, an issue has been created: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/74888

Comment: but isn't the visible region always a rectangle?

Comment: Yes, the visible part is a rectangle (your phone device) but the geographical area is not a rectangle but a trapezoid !